# How to update specific index of array which is present inside JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript

I have below array which is present inside an object and need to update only index 0 from "ABC" to "XYZ".

```
const input = { 
arr: ["ABC", "FGD", "PQR", "TYS"]
};

const desiredOutput = {
arr: ["XYZ", "FGD", "PQR", "TYS"]
 }
```

Comment: `const desiredOurput = { ...input, arr: ['XYZ', ...input.arr.slice(1)] }`

Comment: It is possible to the same thing for array of object present inside in javascript. For Ex const input = { leftColumn: [
    {
      key: "name",
      label: "Javascript Topic Name",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      key: "id",
      label: "Javasctipt Topic Id",
      type: "string",
    },
  ]} and const desiredOutput = {leftColumn: [
    {
      key: "name",
      label: "React Topic Name",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      key: "id",label:React Topic Id",
      type: "string",
    },
  ]}. Only changing the label value for array of object

Comment: sorry but I do not understand whether your last comment is a question and, if it is a question, what it is that you are asking; could you rephrase, please?

Comment: Yeah last comment is an question. Whether we can perform the same way with array of object. I am finding little bit tricky

Comment: in terms of syntax, you can do it and you will get no error but the result would be that if later on in your code you change, for example, `desiredOutput.leftColumn[1].key = 'foo'` also `input.leftColumn[1].key` will be changed.